# Copy Paste a named Range from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a named range from a template to my current workbook, which is blank. The problem is that I don't have any existing range inside this new workbook. So, I am not able to copy paste the range from other book. This is what I have tried but doesn't seem to be working:

```
Sub cpyRange()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\SVN\Template.xls").Sheets("Report").Range("REPORT")

rng2.Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

MsgBox ("done")

End Sub
```

I want to copy paste all the data inside that range to my current workbook along with it's range name.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two specific issues in your code:
1. PasteSpecial is a method of a Range not a worksheet.
2. Pasting doesn't copy the range name.

The code below does the copy, to cell A1 of the target sheet, and then creates a Name that refers to the selection in the target sheet:

```
Sub cpyRange()
Dim SourceWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim RangeName As String
Dim TargetWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim TargetSheet As Excel.Worksheet

RangeName = "REPORT"
Set SourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\SVN\Template.xls")
SourceWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range(RangeName).Copy
Set TargetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set TargetSheet = TargetWorkbook.Sheets(1)
TargetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
TargetWorkbook.Names.Add RangeName, "='" & TargetSheet.Name & "'!" & Selection.Address
SourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

I added a few more variables, to try to make it a little more flexible.

Comment: This seems to be an option but I wanted my new range to be created with a name of "myRange" not "A1" without any manual intervention. I wonder if there's any utility to rename a range or not? And now I want to append one more range after this; i believe I can't use "A1" in that case.

Comment: + 1 :) @Him: To append to an existing range, you may want to use `UNION` or redefine the range?